# Opendaylight: What is the ActionKey ( how used ?)

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

Consider the following opendaylight code segment:

```
   ActionBuilder ab = new ActionBuilder().setAction(vidcb.setSetVlanIdAction(tab.build()).build());

    ab.setOrder(0);
    ab.setKey(new ActionKey(0));
```

What is the ActionKey ?

I understand setOrder is the order of the instruction in an instruction bucket (?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `setOrder` is the order of the `Action` inside an `Instruction`, as an `Instruction` may contain more than one `Action`s.
- `ActionKey` is the identifier of the `Action`. It can be used to access the specific action. For example, someone might need to keep a map between switches and `Action`s per switch of anything similar.

Comment: Thanks! Cleared up some confusions in my understanding.

Comment: @LostInTheFrequencyDomain Glad that I helped! It would be great if you also could upvote me :)